# What URL does OWIN understand for ipv6 self-hosting?

Tags: asp.net, self-hosting, owin

My application uses self-hosting feature of [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). NuGet package name I use is Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost. I used [following example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) as a base.

Following code works for me to launch host on ipv4 localhost endpoint:

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://127.0.0.1:43666");
```

What do I enter if I want to specify ipv6 address? "http://[::1]:43666" does not work. Exception thrown is [reformatted]:

```
System.Net.HttpListenerException: The network location cannot be reached. For information
   ..about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help
at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.Start(HttpListener listener, 
   ..Func`2 appFunc, IList`1 addresses, IDictionary`2 capabilities, Func`2 loggerFactory)
at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinServerFactory.Create(Func`2 app, 
   ..IDictionary`2 properties)
```

Judging by my inspection of code in reflector, the `HttpAddUrlToUrlGroup` function returned error code 1232

Comment: This seems to work for me. Are you getting any exceptions. If so could you post the exception message here?

Comment: Can you check if you have disabled IPV6 on this computer? I see many articles to help disable IPv6. you can use that to see if you have done that. Example : http://www.techunboxed.com/2012/08/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-8.html

Comment: @Praburaj: `D:\>ping ::1

Pinging ::1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did not find a solution, however following is a workaround, although it will start server on all addresses, including non-local and ipv4:

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://+:43666");
```

Since this question didn't generate any interest I'm closing it

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem and it seemed to be the Account under which the service was running. Need to make sure it's running under NetworkService - both localhost and other variations of URLs should work then :)