# WEB API 2, Selfhost, Access is denied for everything but "localhost"

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, self-hosting

In a WEB API 2 OWIN self host project I get "Access is denied" exception thrown for anything other then localhost in:

```
string baseUrl = http://localhost:2500;
WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseUrl);
```

If I use 127.0.0.1 or an actual IP address of the machine I get this exception. No one ever mentions this problem in their blogs about self hosted web api 2 owin based.

What is the problem here and how do I solve it?

I have found this [Self hosted OWIN and urlacl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642651/self-hosted-owin-and-urlacl) but I get the same exception throw.

Comment: Do you succeed, if you try it as admin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me

[What URL does OWIN understand for ipv6 self-hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707411/what-url-does-owin-understand-for-ipv6-self-hosting)

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://+:43666");
```

I still think this should be mentioned and discussed in the WEB API 2 OWIN tutorials!

Comment: Relevant link: [Running self-hosted OWIN Web API under non-admin account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976425/running-self-hosted-owin-web-api-under-non-admin-account)

Comment: The real secret here is to use the "+" . For some unknown reason Windows will accept a binding with "+" wildcard but not if you specify a url or ip